# How do I fix this hyperref warning for \textsubscript in the chapter title?

Tags: hyperref

```
\chapter[Short Chapter Title \& Lorem\textsubscript{A}]{Long Chapter Title \& Lorem\textsubscript{A}}
```

warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\mathsurround' on input line 1.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\z@' on input line 1.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `subscript' on input line 1.
```

it is compiling, but I still have the warning. I've seen advice for fixing this for mathmode but I don't want the A to be in mathmode italics

Comment: LaTeX sometimes tells you that some things don't work inside PDF bookmarks. In this case, it seems like that includes `\textsubscript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\texorpdfstring{<latex-code>}{<bookmark-text>}` macro provided by `hyperref` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{hello \texorpdfstring{\textsuperscript{world}}{world}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't have any spaces in either string.

Comment: Ah, okay, do you mean `hello world` instead of `helloworld`? Got it, editing right away. Thanks.